# Easier way to publish an APK to Google Play on behalf of public clients

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publish

There are a lot of answers out there for how to publish an APK on Google Play, they involve the following:

1. Creating a Google Play Developer account and pay $25
2. Create a Google Developer App Project
3. Enable the Google Play Developer API is enabled on the project
4. Create a service account on the project and ensure that a role is selected during that process (got tripped up here myself when I didn't add a role)
5. Link the Google Developer App project to my Google Play Developer account and select the service account.

All this seems very technical and complicated when I'm trying to create a service where my clients can go to my site, create a simple mobile app and publish it on Google Play.  I'm not expecting my clients to be technically minded so expecting them to do all this seems like a stretch too far.

Is it possible for me to get my clients to sign in with their google play developer account and do the other parts on their behalf for them?  Or is there a more simpler way?  Or can I publish their APK's on my Google Play Developer account and manage them for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing apps to Google Play on behalf of clients is specifically forbidden by Google Play policy. You should [carefully review the Play Policy on repetitive content](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/spam/repetitive-content/) otherwise your clients may not be happy when their apps are taken down.

> "Apps that are created by an automated tool, wizard service, or based on templates and submitted to Google Play by the operator of that service on behalf of other persons are not allowed. Such apps are only permissible if they are published by an individually registered developer account belonging to the user of the automated tool, not the operator of the service."

Comment: Thank you, I was specifically looking to see if this would be the case but did not come across this.

Answer (score 1):

You want the Google Play publishing API.  See https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing

Comment: Thank you but the Google Play Publishing API can only be used after the above 5 steps have been completed, I'm trying to make it easy for my clients by not having to do the 5 steps above and the Google Play Publishing API does not negate them...unless I'm missing something?